# "This field is required" error using Custom Logic in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

For the first time, I'm trying to use the "Customize the logic" option in Process Builder (in the "Define Criteria for this Action Group").

I added the logic to it, but the text field containing the logic turns red and beneath it displays the message "This field is required."

This is what I tried:

> (ISCHANGED([Account].Name)=True OR ISCHANGED([Account].Phone)=True OR
>   ISCHANGED([Account].BillingCity)=True OR
>   ISCHANGED([Account].BillingCountry)=True OR
>   ISCHANGED([Account].BillingState)=True OR
>   ISCHANGED([Account].BillingStreet)=True OR
>   ISCHANGED([Account].BillingPostalCode)=True OR
>   ISCHANGED([Account].Owner.Id)=True OR
>   ISCHANGED([Account].Website)=True) AND
>   [Account].LastModifiedBy.LastName<>’Service Account’

I also tried putting it inside a big "IF" and using != instead of <>.

Edit: This process runs when an Account is changed.  And the logic is intended to execute the action only when certain fields are edited, and when it is not edited by the "Service Account" user.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details: a) the incoming data b) more information about the process

Comment: Ok I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you populated 'Criteria Name' - this is when I get "This field is required." error. Also, change your formula to the following (you don't need '=True' validation on Boolean):

```
(ISCHANGED([Account].Name) || ISCHANGED([Account].Phone)
 || ISCHANGED([Account].BillingCity) || ISCHANGED([Account].BillingCountry)
 || ISCHANGED([Account].BillingState) || ISCHANGED([Account].BillingStreet)
 || ISCHANGED([Account].BillingPostalCode) || ISCHANGED([Account].Owner.Id)
 || ISCHANGED([Account].Website)
) && [Account].LastModifiedBy.LastName <> "Service Account"
```

Comment: That was it, my formula was not structured correctly.  Also I found that I could enter it after checking the radio button "Formula evaluates to true" rather than where I was trying to use it.  Thanks.